# Reading 1900 U.S. census record?

Tags: united-states, census-records, palaeography

I am doing research into family history and found the 1900 US census with an ancestor in it. The image below has 3 lines and 2 columns where the columns are (part of their) "name" and relationship to the head of the household. The column reads: son, son, daughter [Illegible]. Can anyone make it out?

[image: Nova]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I think it would be helpful to show a few lines after the bottom one, and also anything that you know about this family from the previous and subsequent censuses. I think I can see Clara but it seems to be written over/under another name.

Comment: A quick search shows she is [Nora] Conley, age 9, living with the Fuller family in Braddock Ward 1, Allegheny, Pennsylvania.

Comment: Full census image here: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-267-12395-249735-45

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name: Nora

Relationship: Taken as A Daughter

From the full [census image](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-267-12395-249735-45), she is [Nora] Conley, age 9, living with the Fuller family in Braddock Ward 1, Allegheny, Pennsylvania.